# Parse 2 form-data collections c# and file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi controller that is handling a file upload request.  The data being streamed in for the file upload is in a form-data collection.  There is another form also in the request that has Session information i need.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarya0caUzBoIAiZmKpk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionInfo"

{"sessionId":"CC58F82D-DD87-4EA7-8DEF-42CABA045251","client":"","originalUserId":0,"group":0,"cluster":0}
------WebKitFormBoundarya0caUzBoIAiZmKpk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="import.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

    "Name","Gender","Company"
    "John Smith","male","TestIcon"
    "Jane Doe","female","FastTrucks"
------WebKitFormBoundarya0caUzBoIAiZmKpk--
```

My question how in c# can i separate the the form-data collections to get the correct data?

Right now I have code that parses the import file coming in.  but i am not sure how to get to the `name="sessionInfo"` form-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-JS

`var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files`

`var data = new FormData();
for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
}`

-WebApi

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()  
     {
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
    {
        var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        byte[] fileArray = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(root + filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            await fs.WriteAsync(fileArray, 0, fileArray.Length);
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

}